# Entity Framework meta data

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-assembly

I have a piece of code

```
 using (InContext inContext = new InContext())
```

When I right click the definition, it points to `C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\....`

What is that? A defined dll?

```
    #region Assembly SharedObjects.dll, v4.0.30319
   // C:\source\blah\blah\packages\SharedObjects.1.0.4659.22817\lib\net40\SharedObjects.dll
    #endregion

   using blahSharedObjects;
   using System;
   using System.Data.Entity;

   namespace something
   {
       public class InContext : DbContext
   {
       public InContext();
       public InContext(string connectionString);


        public DbSet<InDetails> InDetailRecords { get; set; }
        public string IPAddress { get; set; }

        public string UserName { get; set; }

   }
```

}

Comment: May you please describe what does `InContext` refer to? Have a great day :)

Comment: The DLL that has the definition of InContext perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location you are referring to is your local user account temp folder. Is the `InContext` class in your `App_Code` folder? Is the name of the `DLL` your referring to the same as your project?

I can only assume it's being built with the solution which in turn put it in the temp folder. Try cleaning/rebuilding to see if it is still the same.

Comment: It is still there and also in a lib folder. Why it introduces meta data?